# How to properly use tf.metrics.mean_iou in Tensorflow to show confusion matrix on Tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, deeplab

I found evaluation script in Tensorflow official implementation of DeeplabV3+ ([eval.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/eval.py)) uses `tf.metrics.mean_iou` to update mean IOU, and adds it to Tensorboard for record.

`tf.metrics.mean_iou` actually returns 2 tensors, one is calculated mean IOU, the other is an opdate_op, and according to official doc ([doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean_iou)), confusion matrix. It seems every time if you want to get calculated mean_iou, you have to call that update_op first.

I am trying to add this update_op into summary as a tensor, but it does not work. My question is how to add this confusion matrix into Tensorboard?

I saw some other threads on how to calculate confusion matrix and add it to Tensorboard, with extra operations. I just would like to know if one can do this without those extra operations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will post my answer here since someone upvoted it.

Let's say you defined `mean_iou` op in the following manner:

```py
    miou, update_op = tf.metrics.mean_iou(
        predictions, labels, dataset.num_of_classes, weights=weights)
    tf.summary.scalar(predictions_tag, miou)
```

If you see your graph in Tensorboard, you will find there is a node named 'mean_iou', and after expanding this node, you will find there is an op called 'total_confucion_matrix'. This is what you will need to calculate recall and precision for each class.

[image]

After you get the node name, you can add it to your tensorboard via `tf.summary.text` or print in your terminal by`tf.print` function. An example is posted below:

```
    miou, update_op = tf.metrics.mean_iou(
        predictions, labels, dataset.num_of_classes, weights=weights)
    tf.summary.scalar(predictions_tag, miou)
    # Get the correct tensor name of confusion matrix, different graphs may vary
    confusion_matrix = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('mean_iou/total_confusion_matrix:0')

    # Calculate precision and recall matrix
    precision = confusion_matrix / tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(confusion_matrix, 1), [-1, 1])
    recall = confusion_matrix / tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(confusion_matrix, 0), [-1, 1])

    # Print precision, recall and miou in terminal
    precision_op = tf.print("Precision:\n", precision,
                         output_stream=sys.stdout)
    recall_op = tf.print("Recall:\n", recall,
                         output_stream=sys.stdout)
    miou_op = tf.print("Miou:\n", miou,
                         output_stream=sys.stdout)

    # Add precision and recall matrix in Tensorboard
    tf.summary.text('recall_matrix', tf.dtypes.as_string(recall, precision=4))
    tf.summary.text('precision_matrix', tf.dtypes.as_string(precision, precision=4))

    # Create summary hooks
    summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
    summary_hook = tf.contrib.training.SummaryAtEndHook(
        log_dir=FLAGS.eval_logdir, summary_op=summary_op)
    precision_op_hook = tf.train.FinalOpsHook(precision_op)
    recall_op_hook = tf.train.FinalOpsHook(recall_op)
    miou_op_hook = tf.train.FinalOpsHook(miou_op)
    hooks = [summary_hook, precision_op_hook, recall_op_hook, miou_op_hook]

    num_eval_iters = None
    if FLAGS.max_number_of_evaluations > 0:
      num_eval_iters = FLAGS.max_number_of_evaluations

    if FLAGS.quantize_delay_step >= 0:
      tf.contrib.quantize.create_eval_graph()

    tf.contrib.training.evaluate_repeatedly(
        master=FLAGS.master,
        checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.checkpoint_dir,
        eval_ops=[update_op],
        max_number_of_evaluations=num_eval_iters,
        hooks=hooks,
        eval_interval_secs=FLAGS.eval_interval_secs)
```

Then you will have your precision and recall matrix summarised in your Tensorboard:
[image]